# Piranha cms automatically add pages in page type builder

Tags: c#, .net-core, piranha-cms

I'm using Piranha cms in one of my projects.

I'm looking for a solution to automatically add all my page types to page Type Builder.

At this moment my startup Configure method look like this:

```
var pageTypeBuilder = new Piranha.AttributeBuilder.PageTypeBuilder(api)
                .AddType(typeof(Models.BlogArchive))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.StandardPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.StartPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.RegisterPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.ApprovePage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.LoginPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.MyOfferListPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.OfferListPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.OfferDetailPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.OfferCreatedPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.OfferAcceptPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.BooksPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.PropertyPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.PropertyListPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.MyBidsPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.AgendaPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.ProfilePage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.CheckoutPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.BidCreatedPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.ForgotPasswordPage))
                .AddType(typeof(Models.ContactPage));
            pageTypeBuilder.Build()
```

I would like to reduce it, if it is possible.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! If you have an up-to-date version of Piranha you can now do the following.

```
new ContentTypeBuilder(api)
  .AddAssembly(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
  .Build();
```

And this will import **all** of the available content types in the specified assembly. Also if you have content types in several assemblies you can add several `AddAssembly` after each other just like with `AddType`.

Best regards

Comment: Would be nice if the same .AddAssembly() call could also automatically register Regions, Blocks, and Fields.

Comment: Good idea, add an issue for it at GitHub!